# Problem to follow links in Samba

Tags: symlink, samba

To get acquainted with Samba I installed it on a Raspberri Pi and and tried to access shares from Windows (7). Everything works so far, except when I try to get more space by mounting an external harddrive and creating a symbolic link to it.

Permissions within RPi Linux seem to be ok, because even if I login via a terminal on Windows into the RPi account I can access the mounted drive.

The mapped network drive on Windows works also well, as long I do not try to follow a symlink located in the home directory of the RPi account. This is true for ANY link, i.e., not necessarily the mounted drive only. The answer always is "Access denied".

Tried also:

```
[global]   
allow insecure wide links = yes

[share]   
follow symlinks = yes   
wide links = yes
```

but it does not help either.